# How to show HTML5 form data in table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

** I have a form with html5 form control.I wanted to how form entered data in below table.
In my code i am able to created data and insert row but after clicking on save button table data got vanished.
please provide you inputs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
                form {
                    /* Just to center the form on the page */
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    width: 80%;
                    /* To see the outline of the form */
                    padding: 1em;
                    border: 1px solid #CCC;
                    border-radius: 1em;
                }

                    form div + div {
                        margin-top: 1em;
                    }

                label {
                    /* To make sure that all labels have the same size and are properly aligned */
                    display: inline-block;
                    /*width: 90px;*/
                    /*text-align: right;*/
                }

                .label-name {
                    width: 20%;
                    text-align: left;
                }

                input, textarea {
                    /* To make sure that all text fields have the same font settings
        By default, textareas have a monospace font */
                    font: 1em sans-serif;
                    /* To give the same size to all text field */
                    width: 300px;
                    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    /* To harmonize the look & feel of text field border */
                    border: 1px solid #999;
                }

                    input:focus, textarea:focus {
                        /* To give a little highlight on active elements */
                        border-color: #000;
                    }

                textarea {
                    /* To properly align multiline text fields with their labels */
                    vertical-align: top;
                    /* To give enough room to type some text */
                    height: 5em;
                    /* To allow users to resize any textarea vertically
        It does not work on every browsers */
                    resize: vertical;
                }

                .button {
                    /* To position the buttons to the same position of the text fields */
                    padding-left: 90px; /* same size as the label elements */
                }

                button {
                    /* This extra margin represent roughly the same space as the space
        between the labels and their text fields */
                    margin-left: .5em;
                }

                input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
                    width: 20px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

                #result_grid {
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    width: 80%;
                    padding: 1em;
                    border: 1px solid #CCC;
                    border-radius: 1em;
                }

                table {
                    border-spacing: 5px;
                }

                button {
                    width: 100px;
                }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <label class="label-name" for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nametxt" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="label-name">Gender:</label>
            <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female" checked><label for="female" class="abc">Female</label>
            <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male"><label for="male" class="abc">Male</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="label-name">Date Of Birth:</label>
            <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="nationlity" class="label-name">Nationality</label>
            <select id="nationlitydd">
                <option value="indian">Indian</option>
                <option value="pakistan">Pakistani</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="language" class="label-name">Language:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="english" name="lang" id="englishchk" checked class="chk" /><label for="english">English</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="hindi" name="lang" id="hindichk" class="chk" /><label for="hindi">Hindi</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="kanada" name="lang" id="kanadachk" class="chk" /><label for="kanada">Kanada</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="punjabi" name="lang" id="punjabichk" class="chk" /><label for="punjabi">Punjabi</label>
        </div>
        <!--<div>
            <label class="label-name">Phone No:</label>
            <input type="number" name="phone_no" required>
        </div>-->
        <div>
            <label for="mail" class="label-name">E-mail:</label>
            <input type="email" id="mailtxt" required placeholder="abc@efg.com" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="photo" class="label-name">Photo:</label>
            <input type="file" name="File1" id="File1" accept="image/*" placeholder="Upload your photo" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="msg" class="label-name">Message:</label>
            <textarea id="msgtxt" placeholder="Add your message"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="button">
            <button type="submit" onclick="savedata();">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="result_grid">
        <div id="edit_view_panel">
            <!--<input type="button" value="View" />
            <input type="button" value="Edit" />-->
            <button type="submit" value="View"> View </button>
            <button type="submit" value="Edit"> Edit </button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table id="form_result">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>DOB</th>
                    <th>Nationality</th>
                    <th>Language</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Photo</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var checkedValue = [];
    var row;
    var data;

    function getRadioValue(theRadioGroup) {
        var elements = document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup);
        for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (elements[i].checked) {
                return elements[i].value;
            }
        }
    }

    function getCheckBox(thisCheckBoxGroup) {
       // var checkedValue = [];
        var inputElements = document.getElementsByName(thisCheckBoxGroup);
        for (var i = 0; inputElements[i]; ++i) {
            if (inputElements[i].checked) {
                 checkedValue.push(inputElements[i].value);              
            }

        } return checkedValue;
    }

    function savedata() {

        var nationaldd = document.getElementById("nationlitydd");
         data = {
            "name": document.getElementById('nametxt').value,
            "gender": getRadioValue('gender'),
            "dob": document.getElementById('dob').value,
            "nationality": nationaldd.options[nationaldd.selectedIndex].text,
            "lang": getCheckBox("lang"),
            "email": document.getElementById('mailtxt').value,
            "filename" : document.getElementById('File1').value,
            "message": document.getElementById('msgtxt').value
        }
        console.log(data);      
        createtablerow();


    }

    function createtablerow() {

        table = document.getElementById('form_result');    
        var columnCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

         //Add the data rows.
            row = table.insertRow(-1);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(-1);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(-1);
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(-1);
            var cell7 = row.insertCell(-1);
            var cell8 = row.insertCell(-1);

            cell1.innerHTML = data.name;;
            cell2.innerHTML = data.gender
            cell3.innerHTML = data.dob;
            cell4.innerHTML = data.nationality;
            cell5.innerHTML = data.lang;
            cell6.innerHTML = data.email;
            cell7.innerHTML = data.filename;
            cell8.innerHTML = data.message;
             //here i am adding the row
            table.appendChild(row);


    }
</script>
```

//how to get data in TABLE after clicking on save button

Comment: you have a `form` - submitting a form results in the page being reloaded ... either prevent the submit from doing what it's supposed to do by various means, or don't use a form if you're not submitting a form in the first place - or don't have a submit button

Comment: yes by changing the button type submit with inout type button it starts working.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Remove type='submit' from your save button, as it submits the form and refreshes the page. I would remove all submits and would leave only button types and would use submit when the data is ready to be sent to the server.

Comment: Forgot to add, when you are using submit button, you need to add an action attribute to your form tag to specify to which script you are sending data to. Like action="script.php". Good luck!